# Change Contextual ActionBar Close button icon on just one action mode

Tags: android

I have an activity with 2 different action modes (one for copy/paste, and one for editing some text with an EditText). Is it possible to use *different* custom icons for each action mode?

I know about this style:

```
<item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/MyCloseButton</item>
```

But how can I apply that to one of two action modes of the same activity?

EDIT: More generically, is it possible to use 2 styles for two CABs on the same activity?